# Mobile "muonic hydrogen"

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

If we look at the atomic positions in a single crystal sample with a diamond like lattice, there exist directions along which there are long hexagonal "tubes" (I'm not sure if these have a proper term).

[image: hexagonal tubes in diamond like lattice]

This happens in silicon for example.  Now if a hydrogen atom was inserted in the material, it would be too large and just get trapped in the 'matrix' of the silicon and present a defect in the material.

If instead I took a proton and muon in a bound "muonic hydrogen" state, the bohr radius which goes like 1/m would be ~ 200x's smaller.  Due to being neutral, small, and tightly bound (a binding energy > 2.5 keV), I am tempted to view it almost like a large neutron.

My question is:
Due to its much smaller size, could such a 'large neutron' pass freely through a crystal along one of these tubes?
Could one eliminate trapped hydrogen in a crystal by making it "mobile" in this fashion by putting the sample in a muon beam of low enough energy that it won't damage the crystal structure but still create 'muonic hydrogen'?

Answer (score 1):

On the specific "muonic hydrogen" part of the question: yes it will be much more compact than hydrogen and would probably fit but I see difficulties in generating such a beam that will last long enough  at the necessary low energy and be incorporated in the crystal.

A muon decays in about 10**-6 seconds. So a beam of muonic hydrogen could tunnel through a crystal along the axis  and not scatter destructively, but I find it improbable it will be captured within. Anyway the muon will decay and the proton will be an imperfection in the lattice.

Beams of particles have been [tunneled through crystals](http://cdsweb.cern.ch/record/366497/files/sl-98-059.pdf). The problem will be in targetting interstitial hydrogen because nothing guarantees it will be along the crystal axis.

Comment: The decay time is not that big a constraint--- a microsecond is a long time, at thermal velocity its almost 10cm.

Answer (score 1):

Mu-hydrogen has a large electric dipole response to external electric fields, will likely wind up getting close to a heavy nucleus, and transferring the muon to the nucleus and shedding the proton. The empty tubes are filled with electronic density anyway, and I don't see any reason that the scattering of mu-hydrogen should be small, considering that it has charged constituents far apart as compared to a neutron.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of particle [channelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channelling_%28physics%29).  A particle can pass through planes or “tubes” in crystals of this nature.

Comment: John asks about diffusion of that "muon-hydrogen" in silicon lattice. That is rather different from channeling of subatomic particles!